# Psalm check for calls to "die"

Tags: php, psalm-php

Is there a way to configure Psalm that calls to [`die` or `exit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) cause an error?

I have trouble with a codebase that heavily uses these two commands and want to at least avoid people adding new die commands that should not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Psalm 4.12 you can forbid both `die()` and `exit()` by listing them in `<forbiddenFunctions>` config section:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<psalm
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="https://getpsalm.org/schema/config"
>
<!-- ...... -->
    <forbiddenFunctions>
        <function name="exit" />
        <function name="die" />
    </forbiddenFunctions>
<!-- ...... -->
```

###### Outdated answer

Not currently, but it should be fairly easy to add. Please file an issue here: https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/issues